# Fetch content from MYSQL database not showing line breaks (MYSQL, SEQUALIZE, NODE, HANDLEBARS)

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

Using a database management tool (HeidiSQL) I can see that the content of an entry is storing returns (good):

MYSQL storing line breaks

[image: 1]

However when I read the data on my front-end:

```
router.get('/story/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getStory = await Story.findByPk(req.params.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ['username'],
        },
      ],
    });

    const story = getStory.get({ plain: true });
    
    res.render('story', {
      story,
      logged_in: req.session.logged_in,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Rendered in Handlebars:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="title">
      {{story.title}}
    </p>
    <p class="content">
       {{story.content}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It eliminates the line-breaks:
[no line-breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ6y5.png)

I'm wondering what I need to do to maintain the linebreaks.

I haven't tried modifying anything yet. I will try encapsulating the handlebars {{story.content}} in a string-literal to see if that does it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer - I needed to add a custom handlebars helper in the server.js

```
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('breaklines', function(text) {
  text = hbs.handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
  text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br>');
  return new hbs.handlebars.SafeString(text);
});
```

Then pass the content through the helper

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="title">
      {{story.title}}
    </p>
    <p class="content">
       {{breaklines story.content}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```